# Banned from the only store around

Tags: florida, conflict-of-interest

I was involved in a self-defense shooting where I was in the right it did not happen on the store property for some reason I'm not allowed in the store anymore and it's the only one around I didn't do nothing wrong

Comment: I believe you are asking if the store is breaking any laws by not letting you in?

Comment: So? What is your question?

Comment: There seems to be a common misunderstanding that discrimination for any reason is illegal by default. It is not, for private entities. The store owner has the right to exclude (discriminate against) anyone for any reason unless that particular reason is prohibited by law. "People who have been involved in self-defense shootings" is not a protected class, so they can discriminate against you on that basis. They could not discriminate against you based on religion, sex, race, or possibly a few other reasons, but the general rule is "private property owners decide who can and can't be on their...

Comment: ...property." They couldn't say "no black people allowed" or "no women allowed" or "no Muslims allowed," but they can say "no people involved in self-defense shootings allowed." They could probably even say "no gun owners allowed," even if the gun owner wasn't carrying a gun at the time. Unless they are specifically forbidden from discriminating, they are allowed to. They could probably also say "no Democrats allowed," "no dog owners allowed" (except service dog owners; disability is another protected class). It's important to note that even if you are a member of a protected class...

Comment: ... they can still discriminate against you for other reasons: if they refuse to allow a disabled black Muslim woman from entering because she has shot someone in self-defense, or because she's a Democrat, or because she's a dog owner (as long as the dog isn't a service dog), that's legal.

Comment: If you think it should be illegal to discriminate against someone because of an action they took in self-defense, you should ask your legislators to make that a law. If you want something to be illegal but it isn't currently, that's a political issue, not a legal one; suing the store won't accomplish anything. (Remember that political views aren't protected against discrimination, though; if you publicly support this law, more businesses might discriminate against you, and they will be within their legal rights.)

Comment: And of course, the usual disclaimer: I am not a lawyer; this is not legal advice.

Answer (score 3):

If you are in Florida, the notion that this is "the only store around" is simply not accurate. I doubt that there is any place in Florida that is not within 15-20 miles of at least two stores.

In any case, the store is within its rights to ban you from the store even if you acted lawfully.